# angular 2 filter BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, filter, angular2-observables, array-filter, behaviorsubject

i try to filter a BehaviorSubject in Angular 2. The commissions object in the service will get data via a http request. But because it's instanced with "null" there is an error at the filter code line.

The error:

> Cannot read property '0' of null

at `.filter((commission: Commission[], index) => commission[index]._id === this.commissionid)`

Here ist the code:

commissionService:

```
public commissions: Subject<Commission[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Commission[]>(null);
```

in the component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.commissionService.commissions
        .filter((commission: Commission[], index) => commission[index]._id === this.commissionid)
        .subscribe(data => {console.log(data); })
  }
```

Is it possible at all that this filter will work if I change the this.commissionid? Thanks!

Comment: `Observable#filter` does not take an `index` parameter. I suspect you want `commissions.map(commissions.filter(...))`.

Comment: @torazaburo It actually does take an index as second parameter. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers but i'am sorry, i was wrong, i have problem with this.commissionid is undefined, i have to check this out

Answer (score 3):

You want to have a single object from your subject, so use rxjs `first` operator. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html

```
init_obj(id) {
    this.commissionService.commissions
        .first(c => c._id === id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.commission = data;
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now i found a solutions, thanks for you help, here the complete code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.commissionid = params.commissionid;
      if (this.commissionid) { this.init_obj(this.commissionid); }
    });

  }


  init_obj(id) {
    this.commissionService.commissions
        .map(function(data) {
          if (data) { return data.find(commission => commission._id === id); }
        })
        .subscribe(data => {
          if (data) { this.commission = data; }
        })

  }
```

Comment: Now I see what you are trying to do. In this case, you are better off using the `first` operator from rxjs. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html I will update my answer.